# Has there ever been a notable proposal to amend Article V of the U.S. Constitution?

Tags: united-states, constitution, amendment

## Background

In the U.S. Constitution, the process by which the Constitution can be amended is laid out in [Article V](https://www.archives.gov/federal-register/constitution/article-v.html):

> **Article V**
>
> The Congress, whenever two thirds of both houses shall deem it necessary, shall propose amendments to this Constitution, or, on the application of the legislatures of two thirds of the several states, shall call a convention for proposing amendments, which, in either case, shall be valid to all intents and purposes, as part of this Constitution, when ratified by the legislatures of three fourths of the several states, or by conventions in three fourths thereof, as the one or the other mode of ratification may be proposed by the Congress; provided that no amendment which may be made prior to the year one thousand eight hundred and eight shall in any manner affect the first and fourth clauses in the ninth section of the first article; and that no state, without its consent, shall be deprived of its equal suffrage in the Senate.

Based on the text given, there seems to be nothing that states Article V itself currently cannot be amended, and law professor [George Mader is in agreement](https://scholarship.law.marquette.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=5293&context=mulr) while even stating that minor attempts have been made toward this.  This has led me to ask the question...

## Question

Has there ever been a serious, notable legislative proposal to amend Article V of the U.S. constitution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There have been zero serious or notable legislative or State efforts to amend Article V of the US Constitution between March 4th, 1789 and August 14th, 2019. This covers the time period from the formal start of the US Government under the Constitution, following sufficient ratification.

As noted by the question, Article V lays out the process to amend the Constitution. Making a change here would be secondary to other efforts to Amend the Constitution.

The last effort to Amend the Constitution was in the 1970s for the 26th Amendment. This is excepting the 27th Amendment, largely because it originated in 1789, and was ratified largely on a lark.